# Enforce Static Storage at Compile-time

Tags: c++, c

I have a structure that I'd like to enforce static storage on.  This is a vector type on a DSP, and accidentally declaring it on the stack is a common error for users that causes stack overflow, performance issues or both.  As far as I know, this isn't possible, but I'm curious if anyone else knows better.

Example use case:

```
static Vector64 v1;  // OK
static Vector64 v2;  // OK
static Vector64 result; // OK
result = v1 * v2; // OK

Vector64 v3; // I would like this to give a compile-time error
Vector64 v4;
result = v3 * v4;
```

My compiler is Clang/LLVM 3.2, and compiler-specific attributes are fair game.

Comment: I know how (with C++) to allow only dynamic storage (prevent static and automatic), or prevent dynamic storage (only static and automatic allowed), but I don't believe that you can differentiate static storage duration from automatic storage duration.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't be terribly difficult to give a runtime warning (turn that on in debug mode only, please).

Comment: Can you use custom heap allocation? You could hide `Vector64` instantiation behind factory and force fully-controlled heap storage by using custom allocator (aligned if needed).

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you have a particular implementation on that run-time warning?  I could work with that.

Comment: @Drop There's no heap on the platform unfortunately, but I'm considering rolling my own simple allocator for this purpose specifically.

Comment: @SamCristall: Since you don't have a heap, any destructor that runs before the end of `main` is an automatic.  So set a global flag at the end of `main` (you can use a local variable destructor in main to help), and check it from `Vector64::~Vector64()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C has no classes, I would pretty much rule this out.

In general, in C++ when you define a class you cannot control whether objects of that type will be defined `static`ally, on the stack, on the heap, `const` or not `const`, in an array or a member of another class.  These are choices up to the users of the class.

*There are some tricks to keep it off the heap (e.g. playing with `operator new`), or only on the heap (e.g. using the generator pattern) but thats not what you want*

I would love to see how this is possible, but until such time, I'm pretty sure you cannot.

Comment: You can override operator new on a class and declare it as private. This will generate a compile error if there's any attempt at heap allocation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to settle for a runtime error and to wade deep into implementation waters, and *if* your DSP has a suitable address layout, you might simply insert a check for the location of `this` in Vector64's default constructor.

If you know the address space ahead of time the safest thing (language-wise) is to simply compare the absolute position of the stack.

```
struct Vector64 {
    Vector64() { assert( reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this) < STACK_START ); }
};
```

A riskier but more flexible definition might look like this:

```
__attribute__((noinline)) Vector64() {
    int test;
    assert( less<void*>()(this, &test) );
}
```

Where `__attribute__((noinline))` is needed to prevent clang from ordering the allocation of `test` before the Vector64 object (or simply define it elsewhere). On the bright side, reordering optimizations can not cause this assert to throw a false positive, only fail silently. `std::less` is also important here, as unlike `<` it explicitly permits the comparison between addresses of different objects.

This approach is pretty nasty, but by interfering in construction it's the best chance you have of preventing stack overflows at runtime by ensuring no more are constructed.

Answer (score -2):

If you are programming on C you are going to have problems with that. With C++ it should work. I have never used that compiler but both languages are quite different in this matters. Check up your compiler.

Comment: I tagged as both because I'm comfortable using of a solution from either language.  We typically use C++11, but we build from a variety of sources for any single project (ASM/C/C++)

Comment: Can you show *how* this will work with C++?  AFAIK if this is possible, it is not intuitive and would be very difficult.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum why do you think it's possible?  AFAIK it is not, but I'd love to proved wrong!

Comment: @SamCristall - I don't see how it is possible, but I didn't want to rule out somebody being smarter than me, so I said *if*.  This answer says, "With C++ it should work" so I wanted to see how.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Ahh, reading comprehension fail on my part.  Carry on!